# Why can't I use an equality in order by with select distincts?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have

```
select distinct id, flavor from bageltown order by id, flavor
```

This works.

But if I say

```
select distinct id, flavor from bageltown order by id, flavor='lox' desc, flavor
```

I get an error that an element's not present in the distinct clause.

This is, of course, fixed by editing the query to read as such:

```
select distinct id, flavor='lox', flavor from bageltown order by id, flavor='lox' desc, flavor
```

But I'm wondering - why is adding the boolean column to my output necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `DISTINCT` (rather than `DISTINCT ON`) is to remove duplicate rows in the resulting table. This may not be a concern in your particular case (since you've got `id` in the results table), but if you sort by `flavor='lox'` and `flavor='lox'` isn't a result column, there's no guarantee that there aren't some rows represented that (if it weren't for duplicates being removed) had both `flavor='lox'` and `flavor<>'lox'`, and it's not clear how those should be sorted. If you treat `flavor='lox'` and `'flavor<>'lox'` as separate rows, then you're back to having duplicate rows in the table.

Comment: This makes sense!  The deduplication process is destructive, so it may remove rows relevant to sorting, or it might not, so it doesn't know how to sort it.